# Send data in a single mail if RAName is same in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently with my code what happening is, If the `RAName` is same the mail is going multiple times.

What I want is, if the `RaName` is same the data should go in the single mail with data to that `RAname`.

Here is what I get in the mail.

[image: mail sc]

and this is what my code looks like:-

```
for (int i = 0; tb_RA.Rows.Count > 0; i++)
{
    sbodyMail = "Dear " + tb_RA.Rows[i]["RAName"].ToString() + ", <br /><br />  " +

    "Below are the details of the Inward related things. <br /><br /> ";

    sbodyMail = sbodyMail + "<table style='width: 400px;font-size:12px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' " +
                "border='0'><tr><td style='width: 100%;'></b><td></tr></table> " +

                "<table style='width: 450px;font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;height: 53px' border='1'><tr> " +
                    "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>UserName</strong></td> " +
                "<td style='width: 150px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>Document type</strong></td> " +
                    "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>No of Documents</strong></td> ";

    sbodyMail = sbodyMail + "<tr>" +
        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + tb_RA.Rows[i]["userName"].ToString() + " </td> " +
        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + tb_RA.Rows[i]["Document_Type"].ToString() + " </td> " +
        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + tb_RA.Rows[i]["CountofDocNo"].ToString() + " </td> ";

    sbodyMail = sbodyMail + "</table><br>" + //close of header

"Please login with the link <b>http://akruticity/psiterp/ </b> <br /><br /> " +

"<b>THIS IS A SYSTEM GENERATED MAIL. PLEASE DO NOT REPLY </b>";

    ce.SendEmail("test@test.in", "", "", "Inward Reminder mail", sbodyMail,
                    "AUTOSQL", "Powersoft", ls_attach, "ConnectionString");
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also have a look at my DB datatable.

[image: DB]

**UPDATE**

Adding attachment and sending through mails:

```
                        string startupPath = "";
                    List<string> ls_attach1 = new List<string>();

                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    startupPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

                    foreach (var groupss in groups)
                    {
                        ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(startupPath + "\\Attachment\\Reminder_Sheet.xls", ds);
                    }
                    ls_attach1.Add(startupPath + "\\Attachment\\Reminder_Sheet.xls");
                    foreach (var attach in ls_attach1)
                    {
                        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attach));
                    }
                    foreach (Attachment attachments in mail.Attachments)
                    {
                        attachments.Dispose();
                    }

                    ce.SendEmail("nadeem.khan@powersoft.in", "", "", "Information on documents for processing", sbodyMail,
                                 "AUTOSQL", "Powersoft", ls_attach1, "ConnectionString");
```

**Currently attachment is going with all the data to each user. Instead it should go to its relevant data only**

Comment: If I get it right, you want to have table with multiple rows instead of multiple tables. right? then you have to group by your data first and then create body on each

Comment: @AshkanSirous: Yes, you are right and I already have group by on my datatable. Now ?

Comment: something like this:
foreach(var item in groupbylist)
{
var tempList=normalList.Where(nl=>nl.email== item.email);
foreach(var myRow in templist)
{
      "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + tb_RA.Rows[i]["userName"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                           "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + tb_RA.Rows[i]["Document_Type"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                           "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-}
}

Comment: if you dont mind, put this as an answer, SO I can view it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the table and iterate through the collection.

Logic

```
var groups = tb_RA.AsEnumerable() // gets an enumerable collection of datarows
        .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("RAName")); // groupby using RAName

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    // each group will have the group.Key as group's RAName
    //...
    //...

    //group will have DataRow collection inside it
    foreach (var row in group)
    {
        // get each row and fill it in the tr
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Pseudo Code

```
    var groups = tb_RA.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("RAName"));
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        sbodyMail = "Dear " + group.Key + ", <br /><br />  " +

        "Below are the details of the Inward related things. <br /><br /> ";

        sbodyMail += "<table style='width: 400px;font-size:12px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' " +
                    "border='0'><tr><td style='width: 100%;'></b><td></tr></table> " +

                    "<table style='width: 450px;font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;height: 53px' border='1'><tr> " +
                        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>UserName</strong></td> " +
                    "<td style='width: 150px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>Document type</strong></td> " +
                        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>No of Documents</strong></td> ";
        foreach (var row in group)
        {
            sbodyMail += "<tr>" +
                "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["userName"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["Document_Type"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["CountofDocNo"].ToString() + " </td> " +
                "</tr>";
        }

        sbodyMail += "</table><br>" + //close of header
            "Please login with the link <b>http://akruticity/psiterp/ </b> <br /><br /> " +
            "<b>THIS IS A SYSTEM GENERATED MAIL. PLEASE DO NOT REPLY </b>";
        ce.SendEmail("test@test.in", "", "", "Inward Reminder mail", sbodyMail,
                     "AUTOSQL", "Powersoft", ls_attach, "ConnectionString");

    }
```

Comment: perfect naveen, if I get an explanation of the logic which you applied then it would be great for me :)

Comment: thats in the comments. step through the code. the key is in grouping the whole thing

Comment: need to ask one thing here, as per `AsEnumerable()` documentation from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) It says that, it will work from version 3.5ver. So what should I use in replacement for lower version ?

Comment: you will have to iterate through the rows in the datatable and add it to a generic list, ie `List<T>`. Then you can group that collection

Comment: okay, but I haven't used that in past. Any documentation link on msdn for the same ?

Comment: are you still on framework 2.0? that will be some task in framework 2.0

Comment: Actually my local version is 3.5 but when I will update this functionality on production server whose version is 2.0 i am afraid that it won't work their. So that's why I was asking for some substitute for the same logic.

Comment: I haven't touched 2.0 since like 7 years. dont even make me remember those 2.0 days :)

Comment: no issues @naveen. Still I appreciate your logic for helping me this out. I will the way for that too. Thanks for your solution with perfect comments.

Comment: Hi naveen, i added some more code for attachment further to this. here what happening is the attachment is going with all the data to all the `RAName`. Instead it should go their respective user data. Please see updated question for more info. Please suggest where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets say that you have all your data in a strongly typed list like this:

```
class Data
{
    public string RAName { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string Document_Type { get; set; }
    public int CountofDocNo { get; set; }
}
```

You need to select your RAnames first:

```
var raNames = data.Select(d => d.RAName).Distinct();
```

Then on each RAName you can create the email body:

```
    foreach (var raName in raNames)
            {
   var sbodyMail = "Dear " + raName + ", <br /><br />  " ...
```

and for the body

```
var emailData = data.Where(d => d.RAName == raName);
            foreach (var item in emailData)
            {
                sbodyMail = sbodyMail + "<tr>" +
                    "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + item.userName + " </td> " +
                    "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + item.Document_Type + " </td> " +
                    "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + item.CountofDocNo + " </td> ";

            }
```

So your whole code will be something like this:

var raNames = data.Select(d => d.RAName).Distinct();
        foreach (var raName in raNames)
        {

```
        var sbodyMail = "Dear " + raName + ", <br /><br />  " +
```

"Below are the details of the Inward related things. 
 ";

```
        sbodyMail = sbodyMail + "<table style='width: 400px;font-size:12px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' " +
                    "border='0'><tr><td style='width: 100%;'></b><td></tr></table> " +

                    "<table style='width: 450px;font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;height: 53px' border='1'><tr> " +
                        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>UserName</strong></td> " +
                    "<td style='width: 150px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>Document type</strong></td> " +
                        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;color:black;background-color:" + strcolorHead + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>No of Documents</strong></td> ";
        var emailData = data.Where(d => d.RAName == raName);
        foreach (var item in emailData)
        {
            sbodyMail = sbodyMail + "<tr>" +
                "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + item.userName + " </td> " +
                "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + item.Document_Type + " </td> " +
                "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + item.CountofDocNo + " </td> ";

        }

        sbodyMail = sbodyMail + "</table><br>" + //close of header

    "Please login with the link <b>http://akruticity/psiterp/ </b> <br /><br /> " +

    "<b>THIS IS A SYSTEM GENERATED MAIL. PLEASE DO NOT REPLY </b>";

        ce.SendEmail("test@test.in", "", "", "Inward Reminder mail", sbodyMail,
                        "AUTOSQL", "Powersoft", ls_attach, "ConnectionString");
    }
```